# Ctags not generated for .haml and .less files

Tags: vim, haml, less, ctags

I am using ctags -R * to generate tags.But its not generating the tags for .haml and .less files. Is there a separate option to generate tags for these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think haml is supported in ctags by default. Here are the supported languages: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html. You could probably add support for it with a bit of googling.

Answer (score 3):

To add support for less, paste this in your ctags file:

```
--langdef=less
--langmap=less:.less
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,media,medias/
```

The above expressions are `ctrl-]` friendly.
If you're using scripts like kien/ctrlp.vim, use

```
--langdef=less
--langmap=less:.less
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/.\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/#\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,media,medias/
```

it'll add `.` before classes and `#` before ids.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the list of supported languages with

```
$ ctags --list-languages
```

There are some patches for *Exuberant Ctags* that add native support for more languages, but I haven't yet seen anything for *haml* or *less*. However, you can add support via regular expression definitions in your `~/.ctags`; see the [ctags help](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html).